# Saving entities with @ManyToOne relation in Spring JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `Request`:

```
@Entity
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long candidate;

    @ManyToOne
    private ExamSchedule examSchedule;

...
```

Also, `ExamSchedule` :

```
@Entity
public class ExamSchedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private Instant start;

    @NonNull
    private Instant end;

...
```

Now, to save `Request` along with `ExamSchedule` :

1. I will be checking whether an exam schedule present for the given request.
2. If yes, store new `Request` by associating with existing `ExamSchedule`
3. If no, store new `Request` by associating with newly created `ExamSchedule`

In second case above, it is associating newly created `ExamSchedule` with `Request`. Here, it is expected that, it should not create new instance of `ExamSchedule` and use existing one.

Please let me know what could be missing here.
Thanks.

```
Optional<ExamSchedule> scheduleOptional = examScheduleRepository
                .findByStartAndEnd(schedule.getStart(), schedule.getEnd());

        ExamSchedule examSchedule = scheduleOptional
                .orElse(examScheduleRepository.save(schedule));

        Request request = new Request(scribe.getId(), candidate.getId(), examSchedule);
        return requestRepository.save(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

That was a silly mistake.
`orElse` of optional executes its parameter irrespective of whether optional is empty or not.
I needed to use `orElseGet`. This provides `Supplier` as input which executes only when optional is empty.

```
ExamSchedule examSchedule = scheduleOptional.orElseGet(() -> examScheduleRepository.save(schedule));
```